# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined in react (firestore)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project where I am taking inputs(texts and files) through a form from different users and storing it on cloud firestore. I've successfully been able to store images from different users on firebase storage but now I am required to retrieve and put the image urls corresponding to different users on the firestore database. I am able to log the urls on console but when i try to add them to the database I get an error. I am using the following code:

```
    state ={
    selectedFile1:null,

  }

  fileSelectedHandler1 = e =>{
    this.setState({
      selectedFile1: e.target.files[0]
    })
fileUploadHandler1=()=>{
    const storageRef = storage.ref('images/');
    const fileRef = storageRef.child(this.state.selectedFile1.name)
    var uploadTask=fileRef.put(this.state.selectedFile1)
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
      // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
      // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
      var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
          console.log('Upload is paused');
          break;
        case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
          console.log('Upload is running');
          break;
      }
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }, function() {
      // Handle successful uploads on complete
      // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
      uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        this.setState({downloadURL})

      });
    });

  }

<Input type="file" name="image1" id="image2" onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler1}/>
        <button onClick={this.fileUploadHandler1}>Upload</button>

//uploading data to firestore through onSubmit form

addProd = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const db = firebase.firestore();
  
    const userRef = db.collection("Users").add({
        prodname: this.state.prodname,
        prodprice: this.state.prodprice,
        prodcat: this.state.selectedView,
        prodsize: this.state.prodsize,
        proddetails: this.state.proddetails,
        prodsubcat: this.state.prodsubcat,
        prodimgurl: this.state.downloadURL

    });  
    this.setState({
        prodname:'',
        prodprice:'',
        prodsize:'',
        proddetails:'',
        prodsubcat:'',
        selectedView:'Men',

    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three calls to `this.setState()` in the code here.  I'll take a guess at which one the error message is referring to (though that is something you should point out in your question).

Here is your file upload completion callback:

```
    }, function() {
      // Handle successful uploads on complete
      // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
      uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        this.setState({downloadURL})

      });
```

You are using the `function` keyword here instead of an arrow function like you are in other places.  This will change the meaning of `this`, which is causing the error.  You will want to use another arrow function again:

```
    }, () => {
      // Handle successful uploads on complete
      // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
      uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        this.setState({downloadURL})

      });
```

See also:

- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: That didn't work, is there any other way i could send these urls to firestore ? do i really have to use a state ?